# One or two structural equation models if DVs are not theoretically related?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

I have four DVs and 3 IVs. The IVs predict all DVs. The DVs are split into two pairs. That is, DV1 is theoretically related to DV2 and DV3 and theoretically related to DV4, but there is no theoretical relationship between the DVs otherwise.

Is it OK to run just one structural equation model with all DVs, or should I run two separate ones for each of the DV pairs?

Comment: It (probably) won't hurt to run one model with all four.

Comment: I have since submitted a paper with a multivariate model and the four DVs in the one model. The approach has been accepted, so thank you!